# LINQ to Entities - How to return a single string value from entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I am working in asp mvc 3 app.  I have a model/entity called History.  I have a linq query that returns one value.  Depending on what I do, I either get a "Object not set to an instance" error in the controller when the method is called, or I get a "cannot implicitly convert from string to type Models.History."  So I am looking for assistance in resolving, do I just need to cast it or something?

Here is the method that gives the 'object not set' error:

```
public string GetPastAbuseData(int Id)
{

  var query = (from h in _DB.History
              where h.ApplicantId.Equals(Id)
              select h.AbuseComment).FirstOrDefault();

  return query.ToString();
 }
```

Controller:
     vm.HistoryModel.AbuseComment = repo.GetPastAbuseData(Id);

And if I change the method type from string to History I get the 'cannot convert' error:

```
public History GetPastAbuseData(int Id)
{
    return (from h in _DB.History
            where h.ApplicantId.Equals(Id)
            select h.AbuseComment).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are selecting `AbuseComment` property (which is string) from `HistoryObject`. Thus your code tries to convert string to `History`. Just return whole `History` entity:

```
public History GetPastAbuseData(int Id)
{
    return (from h in _DB.History
            where h.ApplicantId.Equals(Id)
            select h).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Also in first case `query` will be of string type. You don't need to call `ToString` on this variable. Even more, when you fall into `OrDefault()` case, you will have `NullReferenceException`.

```
public string GetPastAbuseData(int Id)
{
  return (from h in _DB.History
          where h.ApplicantId.Equals(Id)
          select h.AbuseComment).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: lazyberezovsky, thank you.  It seems so obvious now that you point it out.  So I just returned the whole model and took the peices I needed in my view.  thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your first example is fine you just need to check for null.

```
public string GetPastAbuseData(int Id)
{

    var query = (from h in _DB.History
          where h.ApplicantId.Equals(Id)
          select h.AbuseComment).FirstOrDefault();

    return query == null ? string.empty : query;
 }
```

Comment: it's OK for string to have `null` value. Why are you replacing it with `String.Empty`?

Comment: A lot of people don't like null values, even for strings. I usually coalesce in that case: return query ?? "";

Answer (score 2):

You can use the null coalescing operator which will check if null and return string.Empty if it is null.  [?? Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

```
public string GetPastAbuseData(int Id)
{
     return _DB.History.FirstOrDefault(h=>h.ApplicantId.Equals(Id)).Select(h=>h.AbuseComment) ?? string.Empty;
}
```